# Como seleccionar solo una lista en css?

Tags: css3

Hice este menú, **pero el problema** es que al tener un submenu y al hacer `:hover` en el `li` **contenedor** de los `sub li`, el efecto que hice, se **aplica al** `li contenedor` y al `submenu` **por donde se está pasando el mouse**, como se arregla aquel problema?

```css
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: black;
 display: table;
 width: 101%;
}
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu > li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}
#menu li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  transition: .8s;
}


#menu li {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Computación</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="js.html">Javascript</a>
<li><a href="fp.html">Fundamentos</a>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Acerca</a>
<ul> 
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por la estructura de tu html, donde cada `<li>` puede contener como hijas multiples `<li>` no estoy seguro de que sea posible lograrlo únicamente con CSS y la pseudoclase `:hover` ya que parado en cualquier `<li>` hija estarás en el contenido de un `<li>` padre.

Una alternativa, utilizando jQuery es:

- Al acceder a un `<li>` agregarle la clase que representa el hover, invocando `e.stopPropagation()` para que el evento `mouseover` no se propague a `<li>` contenedoras.
- Al acceder a un `li` tambien removemos la clase que representa al hover de su padre, ya que se pudo haber accedido con el mouse primero al `li` contenedor (En el ejemplo, primero a Computación, luego a Javascript).
- Al salir de un `<li>` removemos la clase que representa al hover

```js
$('li').on("mouseover",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('menu-item-hover');
    $(this).parents("li").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('menu-item-hover');
    })
});


$('li').on("mouseleave",function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('menu-item-hover');
});
```

```css
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: black;
 display: table;
 width: 101%;
}
#menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: black;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu > li {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100%/3);
}

.menu-item-hover{
  background-color: green;
  transition: .8s;
}


#menu li {
  line-height: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
  <li><a href="cp.html">Computación</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="js.html">Javascript</a> </li>
      <li><a href="fp.html">Fundamentos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<li><a href="cp.html">Acerca</a>
<ul> 
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que ingeniosa tu respuesta ,pero lo resolví haciendo el hover a los links <a>

Comment: Eso es bastante mas sencillo :P